# Неправильная асинхронность GET

Tags: python, асинхронность, tornado

Доброго времени суток всем.

Планирую создать чат, используя `tornado` в качестве comet-сервера. С `tornado` знакомиться только начал, поэтому для начала набросал простейший сервер с двумя URL.

При обращении к одному, соединение должно удерживаться до появления сообщений. По второму URL сервер принимает сообщения.

В следующем коде проблема в том, что каждый `GET`, ожидающий новые сообщения начинает обрабатываться только после того, как предыдущий `GET` на этот же URL выполнится полностью. Хотя иногда (очень редко, обычно при первом запуске скрипта), все `GET` обрабатываются как нужно. Проверяю работу, открывая 3 странички: 2 обращаются к URL, ожидающему сообщения, 1 - отсылает сообщение.

Не могу понять, почему вместо вывода:

```
New waiter, count: 1
New waiter, count: 2
Message sended
```

получается:

```
New waiter, count: 1
Message sended
New waiter, count: 1
Message sended
```

Код:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.concurrent import Future
from tornado import gen

waiters = []

class MessageSender(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        myFuture = Future()
        waiters.append(myFuture)
        print('New waiter, count: {}'.format(len(waiters)))
        message = yield myFuture
        self.write(message)


class MessageReceiver(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        global waiters
        for waiter in waiters:
            waiter.set_result('Some message')
        waiters = []
        print('Message sended')
        self.write('OK')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/tornado/sendmsg', MessageReceiver),
        (r'/tornado/waitmsg', MessageSender),
    ])
    app.listen(8889)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: «При обращении к одному, соединение должно удерживаться до появления сообщений.» — если что, в 2016 году делать так не принято, а принято делать вебсокеты

Comment: Для начала  long polling меня вполне устроит.

Comment: похожий вопрос (та же закавыка с браузерами) [Как gunicorn запустить для обслуживания нескольких потоков?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/436491/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*С tornado не знаком - но предполагаю что знаю в чем дело.*

Это особенность браузера, а не серверного кода. Если несколько раз запросить один и тот же ресурс - браузер загрузит его только 1 раз.

Обойти такое поведение можно следующими способами:

1. Открывать страницу в разных браузерах;
2. Открывать страницу с дополнительным параметром в URL (сервер его проверять не будет - но с точки зрения браузера URL будет разным);
3. Использовать для тестирования не браузер, а консольные утилиты `wget` или `curl`.

Comment: Абсолютно в точку. Только что сам это выяснил: запросы из двух браузеров работают корректно. Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Самое смешное, что ответ на этот вопрос дали на официальном сайте сами разработчики `tornado`: [*My code is asynchronous, but it’s not running in parallel in two browser tabs.*](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#my-code-is-asynchronous-but-it-s-not-running-in-parallel-in-two-browser-tabs)